# Are methods part of objects? or only fields are?

Tags: object-oriented

I wanna be sure if objects "contain" methods just as they contain their fields. Also, when you use the term "object", are you talking specifically about its fields?

Comment: I feel there's an underlying question here which you haven't asked - how is the software you are writing going to be different if we, the Great Illuminati of the Internet, tell you that methods are or aren't part of an object?

Comment: We wouldn't usually say that an object contains methods; while we would say that a class contains methods / method declarations.  A class also contains fields / field declarations, while an object, also known as an instance (of a class), contains instance variables corresponding to fields.  A class and its instances often represent some abstraction, some concept and/or entity, so when we use the term object we're usually referring to an instance of that abstraction, concept, or entity.

Comment: What is your definition of "contain"? What is your definition of "object"? Without knowing how you define "object" and "contain", it is impossible to say whether "objects" "contain" methods. Also, what Philip asked: what is your *actual* Software Engineering problem? How does not knowing the answer to your question prevent you from writing code? And which programming language are you talking about?

Comment: It depends on the language. In Python, for example, there are two ways in which methods are not part of objects: you can think of a method as a function-valued *class* attribute that takes an object as an argument, or the `method` object created *by* the function which actually *contains* the object *and* the underlying function (and in this view, calling the method simply calls the function with the object as an argument, hence the first interpretation).

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the context.

When you are referring to `object` as some instantiated class during runtime, then no - in most languages, the methods are not part of that instantiating. They are not part of the memory layout. They are not contained in the object itself as far as the compiler or runtime or computer are concerned.

When you are referring to an `object` as something you as a programmer are using or designing the software around, then the methods are part of the object. That’s where you access them. That is how you should think of them.